# ANTLR Interpreter running error

Tags: antlr, interpreter, antlr3, antlrv3ide

When i run the interpreter as follows,

[image: Running method]

to create parse tree in ANTLR 3.4(in eclipse 3.7) it shows,

[image: Error message]

> An internal error occurred during: "ANTLR Event Listener". For input
>   string: "false"

When I run the second option `Debug(Java)` it doesn't give any error nor parse tree.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing exactly same problem. i.e On running, the "error" comes up. Strangely, clicking on save, makes the parse tree correctly. If you have sorted out the problem, please share it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By not using the interpreter.

No, it's not joke :). AFAIK, *antlrv3ide* uses the interpreter- and debug-components from ANTLRWorks. And ANTLRWorks' interpreter is rather buggy. However, its debugger works like a charm: so use that.

Comment: I tried the debug also. But it wont display any errors nor the parse tree. But the tester wrote for the grammar showing a error.

Comment: @DarRay, sorry, I don't know what 'a error' is. There's too little information to (try to) help you. Consider posting the grammar, the test input, and explaining how you'r invoking the interpreter.

Comment: This interpreter error gives me even in a new project. Seems like it wont depend on the grammar. Without the parse tree are there any way to debug the code find the errors?

Comment: Please can u tell me how to use the debugger. I have updated the question also. Thanks.

Comment: @DarRay, from your screenshot, the `Run` probably launches the interpreter, and `Debug` probably the debugger. I've never used *antlrv3ide* myself though. So again: do *not* use the interpreter!

Comment: Those both options are in interpreter section in anltride, are you using antlrworks. Im looking forward to move to it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, ANTLRWorks' debugger is great: I use it a lot (press CTRL+D in ANTLRWorks).

Comment: In the ANTLRWorks when i run the debug, it says `Connection Error` `Cannot launch the debugger tab. Time-out waiting to connect to the remote parser.` BTW thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I was using antlr-3.4-complete.jar  ,
but I changed it to antlr-3.2.jar and even if it gives me FailedPredicateExeption
I still able to run it with java in the interpreter and create the grammar tree
in the interpreter .
download antlr jar :[antlr-3.2.jar](http://www.antlr.org/download)

Answer (score -1):

refer `bla` said, my here, change from `antlr-3.5-complete.jar` to `antlr-3.3-complete.jar`, then fix this problem.

for detail, can refer [An internal error occurred during: "ANTLR Event Listener". For input string: "false"](http://www.crifan.com/eclipse_antlr_an_internal_error_occurred_during_antlr_event_listener_for_input_string_false/)